# Sharepoint 2010 web front end servers and services configuration

Tags: spservices, dmz

I have a sharepoint insfrastructure where a document library is made available both locally and on the internet. I have a few web front end servers facing the public (in the DMZ) while having another set inside the secured network for internal use. I also have an application server for sharepoint services inside the secured network.

My goal is to configure sharepoint in such a way that the sharepoint services are available only locally and not via the internet. The users accessing the system online should not benefit of the sharepoint services.

Is this possible on the same farm?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with [Service Application Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc560988.aspx), but you will need to have a different web application for the internet users than the internal users if this is not already the case.